# Swift - Run method from another class

Tags: ios, swift

I was wondering how I could run a method from another class. For example, something like the following code:

```
let newVC: ScoreViewController = ScoreViewController()
newVC.makeScore()
```

The above code won't work for me because in `makeScore()`, I am changing a label's text, which I can't do with the above code because it is creating a new instance. Is there a way to call a method to be run without creating a new instance so that I can change a label's text in `makeScore()`?

EDIT:

How ScoreViewController is added to PageViewController:

```
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Score") as! ScoreViewController
self.addChildViewController(vc)
self.scrollView.addSubview(vc.view)
```

Comment: How are your controllers connected ? Navigation controller, tabbar controller ? Custom segue ? You need to get the instance to that controller , to properly acces the methods

Comment: All of my controllers are in a scrollView. I can't make a new instance of the view controller.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the storyboard?

Comment: It's not going to help. All the view controllers are not connected in the storyboard at all. There is PageViewController with a ScrollView in it, FirstViewController, and ScoreViewController. In PageViewController's code, I add the FirstViewController and ScoreViewController to the ScrollView's subview.

Comment: It would be very helpfull, to know how the hearchy is in image.

Comment: Show the code about how you add ScoreViewController into your PageViewController

Comment: Updated the code into the question

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you've some method in your `FirstViewController` where you're changing the score and showing it in your `ScoreViewController`. The delegation pattern is the possible solution for this problem. In your `FirstViewController` create a protocol for updating score such as:

```
protocol FirstVCScoreDelegate:NSObjectProtocol {

    func makeScore()
}
```

Then inside your `FirstViewController` create a var for this delegate:

```
var delegate: FirstVCScoreDelegate
```

Then in your `PageViewController`, where you are creating the instances of the `FirstViewController` and `ScoreViewController`, set the delegate of the `FirstViewController` to `ScoreViewController`:

```
var firstVC: FirstViewController()
var scoreVC: ScoreViewController()
firstVC.delegate = scoreVC
```

And after this, in your method in the `FirstViewController` where the score is changing:

```
@IBAction func scoreChangeAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        if delegate.respondsToSelector(Selector("makeScore")) {

            delegate.makeScore()
        }
    }
```

This will signal the `ScoreViewController` to update the score. You now have to implement the delegate method inside `ScoreViewController`:

```
extension ScoreViewController: ScoreDelegate {

    func makeScore() {
        //update your label
    }
}
```

I believe this will solve your problem.

**UPDATE**

Try this in your `PageViewController`'s `viewDidLoad:` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboard", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())

        let firstVC : FirstViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("firstVC") as FirstViewController

        let scoreVC : ScoreViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("scoreVC") as ScoreViewController

        firstVC.delegate = scoreVC

        self.addChildViewController(firstVC)
        self.addChildViewController(scoreVC)

        self.scrollView.addSubview(firstVC.view)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(firstVC.view)
    }
```

Comment: The first line gives an error `Declaration is only valid at file scope`

Comment: The last bit of code makes an error though. I put it under import UIKit, and the error says `Use of undeclared type 'ScoreDelegate'`

Comment: var delegate: FirstVCScoreDelegate should be inside your class block

Comment: Ok. The third bit of code isn't working though. The error says `Variable 'scoreVC' used before being initialized`

Comment: you've to set the delegate after you've initialized both the view controllers.

Comment: I've tried putting it before and after, but it still shows the same result error.

Comment: I have tested the code and it works. Check the update.

Answer (score 0):

In the PageViewController, declare a property:

```
class PageViewController {
    var scoreViewController:ScoreViewController
    // ....
 }
```

After initializing the ScoreViewController:

```
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Score") as! ScoreViewController
```

Hold it as a property:

```
self.scoreViewController = vc
```

Then use

```
self.scoreViewController.makeScore()
```

Comment: I get an error on the last two lines: `'FirstViewController' does not have a member named 'ScoreViewController'`. Was I supposed to do something else?

Comment: @Smecla Well, before you assign a property, of course you should declare it in the class.

Comment: When I insert that line, class `PageViewController` displays the following error: `Class 'PageviewController' has no initializers`

Comment: If you don't need initializer, just use `var scoreViewController:ScoreViewController?` to make it an optional. And use `self.scoreViewController!.makeScore()` to call it.

Comment: I'm not sure which version of Xcode you are using. Maybe you can try `self.scoreViewController?.makeScore()`, or use `let ` to unwrap it. This kind of errors are trivial and easy to fix.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I fixed it by changing the three lines to `PageViewController().delegate = ScoreViewController()`. It ran! But it still gives the same error as the beginning: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: It should be solved be making it optional `var scoreViewController:ScoreViewController?` . Did you add the question mark at the end?

Comment: Yes, I did add that in